# Custom Listview with checkbox not clickable

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have created a custom listview with checkbox, the items on the listview are not clickable. what am i doing wrong here, i want to be able to click the items on the list not just the checkbox.

```
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            data = store.getText().toString();
            list.add(data);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_view, R.id.textView1, list);
            ls.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
    ls.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            String click = list.get(arg2).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You Clicked " + click, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

my code for `list_view.xml`

```
    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:text="" />
```

my `activity_main.xml` file

```
   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" >

    </ListView>
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSave"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
    android:text="Save" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesnt work because adding `CheckBox` to `ListView` steals the focus from `ListView` and you are not able click the list item . There is a Workaround , do not use checkbox but instead of it you can use for example Drawable , ImageView or TextView with parameter  `setClickable(true)`  or XML `android:clickable=”true”` . It'll do the thing because you will not lose the focus of the `ListView`